# How to call function from content page Angular JS(Ionic Framework)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi I am newbie to Angular, Ionic. Trying to learn with practice. I have a contoller on my controllers file something like that:

And I have a content pages which all of them runs this controller. Content is something like this:

```
.controller('GuideCtrlx', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    var city = "London";
    $http.jsonp("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=parse&page=" + city + "&prop=text&section=0&callback=JSON_CALLBACK").
    success(function JSON_CALLBACK(data) {
        //stuff goes here
    })
}])
<ion-view title="Cart" id="page2" style="">
    <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
        {{ }}
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I want to call controller function on every page with different city name to get data. Tried to add `ng-init` to `<ion-content` not worked. I have two questions.
 1. How to pass value to controller function from a content page mentioned above?
 2. How to show content only after getting function result?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your API endpoint is not JSONP. Please take a look at the documentation https://www.mediawiki.org/api/rest_v1/

Comment: Does it matters? It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your logic you can try like this

Controller

```
    .controller('GuideCtrlx', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,   $http) {
        // var city = "London";
        $scope.getValue = function(city){

            $http.jsonp("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=parse&page="+city+"&prop=text&section=0&callback=JSON_CALLBACK").
            success(function JSON_CALLBACK(data) {
                $scope.values = data;

      //stuff goes here

   })
            }
```

View 1 (here city is London)

```
<ion-view title="Cart" id="page2" style="" ng-init="getValue('London')">
  <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
    {{values}}
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

View 2 (here city is New York)

```
<ion-view title="Cart" id="page2" style="" ng-init="getValue('New York')">
  <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
    {{values}}
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```